# Is there a pandas function for get variables names in a column?

Tags: pandas

I'm just thinking in a hypothetical dataframe (df) with around 50 columns and 30000 rows, and one hypothetical column like e.g: Toy = ['Ball','Doll','Horse',...,'Sheriff',etc].
Now I only have the name of the column (Toy) and I want to know what are the variables inside the column without duplicated values.

I'm thinking an output like the .describe() function

```
df['Toy'].describe()
```

but with more info, because now I'm getting only this output

```
count     30904
unique        7
top      "Doll"
freq      16562
Name: Toy, dtype: object
```

In other words, how do I get the 7 values in this column. I was thinking in something like copy the column and delete duplicated values, but I'm pretty sure that there is a shorter way. Do you know the right code or if I should use another library?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you looking for df['Toy'].unique()?

Comment: or `df['toy'].value_counts()` if you want each item by its row count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unique()` function to list out all the unique values in your columns. In your case, to list out the unique values in the column name *toys* in the dataframe *df* the syntax would look like

```
df["toys"].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.drop_duplicates()`, which returns a pandas Series:

```
df['toys'].drop_duplicates()
```